# Request Body multiple parameters in springboot using object wrapper not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have 2 classes Student and Finals.
Student.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int marks;
        
    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Student(int id, String name, int marks) {
        
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

Finals.java

```
@Entity
public class Finals {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private int marks;
    private int totalMarks;
    public Finals() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Finals(int id, int marks, int totalMarks) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.marks = marks;
        this.totalMarks = totalMarks;
        
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public int getTotalMarks() {
        return totalMarks;
    }

    public void setTotalMarks(int totalMarks) {
        this.totalMarks = totalMarks;
    }   
}
```

ObjWrapper.java

```
public class ObjWrapper{
    private Student student;
    private Finals finals;
    
    
    public ObjWrapper() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public ObjWrapper(Student student, Finals finals) {
        super();
        this.student = student;
        this.finals = finals;
    }
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public Finals getFinals() {
        return finals;
    }
    public void setFinals(Finals finals) {
        this.finals = finals;
    }
}
```

I would like to take the marks of a particular student from student class and add some marks given by user and update it in the marks column of the Student.
I would also like to add a new row to finals table with id,marks,newmarks.
My code

```
@Autowired
    public StudentRepo studentrepo;
    
    @Autowired
    public StudentService stuservice;
    
    @Autowired
    public FinalsRepo finalsrepo;
    
    @PutMapping("/updatemarks/{id}/{marks}")
    public void putTables(@RequestBody ObjWrapper wrapper,@PathVariable(value = "id") int id,@PathVariable(value = "marks") int marks) {
        Student student = wrapper.getStudent();
        student = studentrepo.getOne(id);
        
        int studentMark = student.getMarks();
        int newMarks = studentMark + marks;
        
        Finals f = wrapper.getFinals();
        f.setId(id);
        f.setMarks(marks);
        f.setTotalMarks(newMarks);
        finalsrepo.save(f);
        
        student.setMarks(newMarks);
        studentrepo.save(student);

    }
```

Error :

```
"message": "Required request body is missing: public void com.example.demo.controller.MainController.putTables(com.example.demo.entities.ObjWrapper,int,int)",
    "path": "/updatemarks/1/50"
```

I am not able to unwrap through object mapper I think, I dont know what is wrong in my code...can anyone help me out....Thanks

Comment: Did you annitated your class with `@RestController`? What is the `PUT` rest http command that you are sending?

Comment: How are you sending the request. Can you post the complete `curl` command?

Comment: Guys......`Optional<Student> optional = studentrepo.findById(id);
  Student s = optional.get();
  int studentMark = s.getMarks();`......................this code does the work as it does not use response body it was throwing an error previously and also `studentrepo.findById(id)` returns an optional<Student> and not student which was an error......Anyways much appriciated for the help guys and sorry for asking this lame question.